# Pandas indexing behaves unexpectedly: df[df.index[0]] => KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have taken a dataframe (with initial index 0...9999) and partitioned by year as such:

```
requests_df = {year : df[df['req_year'] == year] for year in df['req_year'].unique()}
```

As per usual, each sub-frame retains its own index ordering. Then, while trying to index on one of these isolated frames (`df_yr = requests_df[2015]`) I get this really unexpected behavior:

```
for idx in df_year.index:
        qty = frame[idx]['qty_tickets']
```

causes:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 8666
```

Thinking I goofed on the iterator, I tried a simple case:

`df_yr[df_yr.index[0]]`

```
KeyError
```

wat.

8666 is definitely the index value for the first row:

```
Int64Index([8666, 8667, 8668, 8669, 8670, 8671, 8672, 8673, 8674, 8675,
            ...
            9830, 9831, 9832, 9833, 9834, 9835, 9836, 9837, 9838, 9839],
           dtype='int64', length=1174)
```

Indexing using loc,

```
outframe.loc[8666]
```

which I though relies on the df.index values, works fine. *wat.*

df.ix also works, which isn't *too* surprising, as it has fallbacks built in.

I've indexed using manipulations of df.index dozens of time with no problem. What gives?

Comment: Try change `qty = frame[idx]['qty_tickets']` to `qty = frame.loc[idx, 'qty_tickets']`

Comment: `df[i]` performs column label-based indexing by default. Both `df.loc[i]` and `df.ix[i]` perform row indexing.

Comment: @IgorRaush you have shown me the error of my ways! I assumed since slices like `df[2:4]` would work, and I've gotten so used to masking (`df[df['foo'] == 'bar]` stuff) that I have forgotten that simple row indexing fails after a df has already been masked. Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `df[index]` will perform *column label-based indexing*. As you noticed, the exceptions are

- `df[slice]` will slice rows
- `df[boolean_mask]` will select a subset of rows based on the mask

Other than these two exceptions, there is no efficient way to disambiguate `df[row_label]` and `df[col_label]`, so Pandas uses the latter interpretation since it's more consistent with "dictionary-like" data frames. Your experiment with `df_yr[df_yr.index[0]]` threw an error because you are attempting to use a row index label where a column index label is expected.

Instead, use *multi-axis label-based indexing*, for which the syntax is

```
df.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]
```

where `col_indexer` is optional. `df.loc[df.index[0]]` should work just fine. In the broken section of your code, use

```
frame.loc[idx, 'qty_tickets']
```

(this is also [noted by jezrael in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376375/pandas-indexing-behaves-unexpectedly-dfdf-index0-keyerror?noredirect=1#comment71901922_42376375)).